# multiple level dropdown menu with javascript. Second dropdown doesnt respond to javascript command

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have created a javascript function where i add and remove classes from certain classes.
This allows me to hide the content and show it again.

The first dropdown responds to the command i created. yet the second dropdown nested within the first, does not respond.

I have tried several things in css to fix this but i cant seem to find it..

```js
// Dropdown menu
let toggle = document.querySelector(".dropdown a");
let sub = document.querySelector(".subMenu");
toggle.onclick = ()=>{
    if (sub.classList.contains("show")){
        sub.classList.remove("show");
        toggle.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
        sub.classList.add("show");
        toggle.classList.add("active");
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #b3b3b3;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
header {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.headerContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
header nav .mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav .mainMenu li a {
    color:darkred;
}
header nav li.dropdown a {
    color:chartreuse;
}
header nav ul.subMenu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul.subMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
/* I TRIED ADDING THIS BUT IT DOESNT WORK */
header nav ul ul.subMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
/* -------------------------------------- */
header nav .subMenu .dropdown a {
    color:aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li class="activepage"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">Diensten<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                            <ul class="subMenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li> 
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#">Marketing<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li> 
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header -->
```

Comment: Hello again. Please tell me which solution did you use?

Comment: Hello @s.kuznetsov, i used your method for my problem.

Comment: Always glad to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using `forEach()` and `nextElementSibling`.
I just changed your js code a little.

Also, use `querySelectorAll()` to refer to the collection:

```
let toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown a");
```

And `nextElementSibling` in your case will allow you to find the first child of `subMenu` class:

```
let sub = toggle_current.nextElementSibling;
      if (sub.classList.contains("show")){
      ...
```

```js
let toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown a");

toggle.forEach(function(toggle_current) {
  toggle_current.onclick = () => {
     let sub = toggle_current.nextElementSibling;
      if (sub.classList.contains("show")){
          sub.classList.remove("show");
          toggle_current.classList.remove("active");
      } else {
          sub.classList.add("show");
          toggle_current.classList.add("active");
      }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #b3b3b3;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
header {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.headerContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
header nav .mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav .mainMenu li a {
    color:darkred;
}
header nav li.dropdown a {
    color:chartreuse;
}
header nav ul.subMenu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul.subMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
/* I TRIED ADDING THIS BUT IT DOESNT WORK */
header nav ul ul.subMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
/* -------------------------------------- */
header nav .subMenu .dropdown a {
    color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li class="activepage"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">Diensten<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                            <ul class="subMenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li> 
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#">Marketing<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li> 
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are using `document.querySelector` which will select only the first matching element. So when you add the `toggle.onclick` function, it is added only to the first matching element. i.e only for **Diensten**. 
So you will have to refactor little bit to use `document.querySelectoAll` to get all the matching elements and use a for loop to iterate over all the items and add the click function to all the items

I've also added a new css style

```
.dropdown a.expand+ ul.subMenu {
  display: block;
}
```

Basically to simply the code... SO when the `<a>` inside the dropdown is clicked, new class called `expand` is added.

```js
// Dropdown menu
let toggleElements = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown a");

for(let i = 0; i<toggleElements.length; i++) {
  const toggle = toggleElements[i];
  
  toggle.onclick = () => {

    if (toggle.classList.contains("expand")) {
      toggle.classList.remove("expand")
      toggle.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      toggle.classList.add("expand")
      toggle.classList.add("active");
    }

  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #b3b3b3;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

header {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.headerContainer,
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.headerContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header nav .mainMenu {
  list-style: none;
}

header nav .mainMenu li a {
  color: darkred;
}

header nav li.dropdown a {
  color: chartreuse;
}

header nav ul.subMenu {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

header nav ul.subMenu.show {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a.expand+ ul.subMenu {
  display: block;
}


/* I TRIED ADDING THIS BUT IT DOESNT WORK */

header nav ul ul.subMenu.show {
  display: block;
}


/* -------------------------------------- */

header nav .subMenu .dropdown a {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="headerContainer">
    <nav>
      <ul class="mainMenu">
        <li class="activepage"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#">Diensten<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
          <ul class="subMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#">Marketing<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
              <ul class="subMenu">
                <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- END header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop all elements inside `dropdown a`, you are using `quertSelector` which returns the first one from the list, you need to use `querySelectorAll` and loops over all element and add `click` and `add` and `remove` class.

**Edit:** Update and fix the code bug.

```js
// Dropdown menu
let toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown a");
toggle.forEach((ele)=>{
  var sub = ele.nextElementSibling;
  //console.log(sub);
  ele.onclick = ()=>{
    if( sub == null){
      return;
    }
      if (sub.classList.contains("show")){
          sub.classList.remove("show");
          sub.classList.remove("active");
      } else {
          sub.classList.add("show");
          sub.classList.add("active");
      }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #b3b3b3;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
header {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.headerContainer, .container {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.headerContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
header nav .mainMenu {
    list-style: none;
}
header nav .mainMenu li a {
    color:darkred;
}
header nav li.dropdown a {
    color:chartreuse;
}
header nav ul.subMenu {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
header nav ul.subMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
/* I TRIED ADDING THIS BUT IT DOESNT WORK */
header nav ul ul.subMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
/* -------------------------------------- */
header nav .subMenu .dropdown a {
    color:aqua;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="headerContainer">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li class="activepage"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#">Diensten<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                            <ul class="subMenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li> 
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#">Marketing<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Graphic design</a></li> 
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- END header -->
```